# FTP upload - Failed to open “C:\Apache24\…\uploads\image2.png” for reading because it is not a file

Tags: git, ftp, filezilla, upload, phpstorm

I would like to upload some files including .php and images to server. I tried it via Filezilla and PhpStorm. All php files has been transferred well, but some images throws me an error with text:

> Filezilla: Failed to open `"C:\Apache24\htdocs\bosp\web\editor_uploads\d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\images\image2.png"` for reading
>
> PhpStorm: could not read from `"file:///C:/Apache24/htdocs/.../uploads/image2.png"` **because it is not a file**. Error: File transfer failed

What does it mean by it is not a file? Pictures has been uploaded via a html form by PHP to the directory, which I want to transfer to server. But FTP throws me this error. Could it be Git issue?

Comment: This sounds like your Apache user has permissions over the file. Can you view the file in Windows explorer?

Comment: No I can't. Windows says "It looks like you don't have permission to view this file. Check the permissions and try again." I don't understand. I am administrator, but I can't seen any properties of this files.

Answer (score -1):

Open Start Menu type Filezilla. Right click on Filezilla and select run as administrator.

[image]